# TypeScript LSP Not Reading tsconfig.json

Tags: neovim, lsp, filetype-typescript

I am almost certain that I have a mistake in my Neovim configuration...  The Neovim `~/.config/nvim` directory I'm using is:

https://github.com/andrewgregorywright/nvim-config/tree/main

I've created an empty project with a single TypeScript file:

```
// src/index.ts

function add(a?: number, b: number, c: number) {
    var x = 42
    return b + c
}

console.log(add(undefined, 5, 2))
```

In the root of the project is a `tsconfig.json` file:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es2022",
    "lib": [
      "es2022"
    ],
    "module": "nodenext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "include": ["*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*"]
}
```

However, when I open `src/index.ts`, there's a warning from the LSP tsserver on the line that contains the function signature for `add` which reads:

> 'a' is declared but its value is never read.

A similar warning occurs on the line below it for the variable `x`.  The `tsconfig.json` file has `noUnusedParameters` and `noUnusedLocals` both set to `false`, but it seems like the LSP server is not using the settings.  I'm not sure what to do.

In `~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/nvim-cmp.lua` the following line configures tsserver:

```
lspconfig.tsserver.setup{}
```

I attempted to find the log files for `tsserver` but wasn't sure where to look.  It was installed globally with `npm`.

Comment: It seems to me that the LSP server  don't consider the configuration file. Did you try to change the current directory to the root of the project? Is the project under git control? What if the ts file is next to the configuration file?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt tsserver should at least be aware of the tsconfig.json file, at least according to [some docs for the nvim-lspconfig plugin](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#tsserver).  (1) Running `git init` in the root directory of the project, (2) `cd src && nvim index.ts`, and/or (3) moving `index.ts` to the root directory of the project did not alleviate the diagnostic warnings, unfortunately.